# Handling nested body in nest js for POST requests

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

A customer sends the below payload to REST end point

```
{
   "name":"Harry potter",
   "address":{
      "street":"ABC Street",
      "pincode":"123",
      "geo":{
         "lat":"123",
         "long":"345"
      }
   }
}
```

The REST endpoint is created using **nestjs/common**  8.0.6 version as `async readPayload(@Body() body:PayloadModel)`. `PayloadModel.ts` is a class written as

```
export class PayloadModel {
name: string,
address : Address
}

export class Address {
street:string,
pincode:string,
geo : Geo
}

export class Geo{
lat:string,
long: string
}
```

When printing body , I'm seeing null values for the nested fields (street,pincode,lat, etc) . What is the correct approach to map all these ?

**Update** This is my controller snippet

```
@Controller('cont')
export class MyController{

@Post('/readme')
async readPayload(@Body() body:PayloadModel){
log.info(body)
}
}
```

Comment: How are you mappinging your `payload` currently?

Comment: i'm relying on readPayload and body to convert it for me.. Just like in a spring controller.

Comment: payload comes in from my postman as raw json in body (application/json header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle a nested body, you have to deserialise the body to the class,
To do that, you can use the package [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer).
Your code would look like this:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class PayloadModel {
name: string,
@Type(()=>Address)
address : Address
}

export class Address {
street:string,
pincode:string,
@Type(()=>Geo)
geo : Geo
}

export class Geo{
lat:string,
long: string
}
```

Comment: it worked. thanks ! I did need to add @IsDefined() and @ValidateNested() also